# PHP version of ASP.net/VB.net Login

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, sha1

I am creating a PHP-version of a login script that is in ASP.net/VB.net. The database where the usernames and passwords are stored is in MSSQL and that will not change. Passwords are stored as binary data. Here's a part of the code in VB.net that compares the password to the one saved in the database.

```
Dim sha1 As sha1 = sha1.Create()
Dim password As Byte() = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Me.txtPwd.Text))
CustData = .GetCustomerByEmail(Me.txtUser.Text, password)
```

I found out that it's part of a [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288544%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

I am encountering problems after hashing the password in PHP's sha1. I don't know how to convert the hashed string to a binary that I could use to compare it to the database.

As an example, the password "Test100" in the MSSQL database has a value of (after unpack('H*', $binaryPassword)) 7397001ce5259b79c436a369b9d3a8c7bc2a85385fdec57a. I am not sure how to get that string above from the hashed password I am getting using PHP.

Here's what I have in PHP so far and where I am stuck in.

```
$password = sha1(mb_convert_encoding($_POST['password'], 'utf-16le'), false); // $_POST['password'] = 'Test100'
```

The output for that is 8415ec8cc9287a10f81db5a77341709d304bfa92.

So I am thinking there's one more step to change $password to $binaryPassword or the hexadecimal representation of the binary password.

From [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.byte%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2), it's saying Byte is an 8-bit unsigned integer, but not really sure how to get that from a PHP string.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try to run the sh1 on the static text "Test100"?

Comment: If I run sha1('Test100') or hash('SHA1', 'Test100') I get 753bf7a73775c66e54e13e63bbf6e5091855f527.